# Induced magnetic field

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

When I induce a voltage in a coil by moving it relative to a magnetic if it is a connected circuit a current will flow thus producing a magnetic field. Does this induced magnetic field affect my calculations using faraday's law? how does the flux changes?

Try to explain it without maxwell's equation, In highschool terms.

Comment: 1) you need a change of magnetic field, so moving it in a homogeneous field would not be enough
2) You talk about Faraday, but do not "allow" Maxwell. What about Ampere?

Comment: I think his question means something like: "A varying magnetic flux causes an induced voltage (according to Faraday-Lenz law) that generates a current that generates a magnetic field that generates another magnetic flux in the same circuit. Does the Faraday-Lenz law include this self induction?"

Comment: mikuszefski I haven't took ampere but If you truly cant explain it without it , you could make a combination

FrodCube Yes, exactly